# How do you use credentials saved by the browser in auto login script

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

When I manually open a browser, both firefox and chrome, and proceed to a website where I previously saved my login credentials via the browser, the username and password fields automatically populate as they should. However, when I use the python selenium webdriver to open the browser to a specific page, the fields do not populate.

The point of my script is to open the webpage and use `element.submit()` to login since the login credentials should already be populated., but the are NOT. 
How can i get them to populate in the fields?

For Example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()    
driver.get("https://facebook.com")    
element = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_v")    
element.submit()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because selenium doesn't use your default browser instance, it opens a different instance with a temporary (empty) profile.

If you would like it to load a default profile you need to instruct it to do so.

Here's a chrome example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

And here's a firefox example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\\Path\\to\\profile")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Here we go, just dug up a link to this in the (unofficial) documentation. [Firefox Profile](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=profile#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) and the Chrome driver info is right underneath it.

Comment: Hey Thanks for all your help. What you gave me worked, for the most part. But first I had to create a new profile in firefox because the default profile wont work.


The username will populate but the password will not populate. I did just use the line `send_keys()` which worked but I rather not have my password sitting in the script.

Comment: You're the hero mate, works like a charm. Btw, I spent some time figuring out the proper path to Chrome Profile, for anyone looking it should be:C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Comment: On Ubuntu, your profile will look something like: `profile = FirefoxProfile("/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxx.default")`

Comment: For those who are interested in the Window path for Firefox C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

Comment: It just opens a blank browser for me.

Comment: This worked for me with Chrome up to a point. When I submit the form, 90% of the time the login fails. Adding delays before submitting doesn't seem to make any difference. Manually pushing the button works. If I have Selenium retype the username and password, it works. I'm not sure why the saved username/password fails to login _only_ when Selenium submits the form.

Comment: You can type chrome://version in your chrome URL and then you can find the path to the chrome profile.

Comment: doesn't work for me either, opens tabs- 1. http://data/default and 2. http://data:;

Comment: firfox profile isn't opening with active logins as in chrome.

Comment: @bmcculley Thank you Brother, I was searching for this solution a months

Answer (score 2):

- **download chromedriver.exe**: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- **show chrome version and profiles**: open chrome and type: "**chrome://version/**" on URL

```
from selenium import webdriver
from os.path import abspath
from os import path
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\...")  # Path to your chrome profile or you can open chrome and type: "chrome://version/" on URL

chrome_driver_exe_path = abspath("./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")  # download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
assert path.exists(chrome_driver_exe_path), 'chromedriver.exe not found!'
web = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_exe_path, options=options)

web.get("https://www.google.com")
web.set_window_position(0, 0)
web.set_window_size(700, 700)
sleep(2)
web.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it navigates to "data/default" you can put your new url in that tab by doing driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0]).

Answer (score 0):

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile num\\")
path = os.path.abspath(filedialog.askopenfile().name)
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path,options=options)
```

before  you do this open chrome and add a profile then go into the profile and paste the contents of the profile into the default dir