# I want to login automatically to a website whenever I run my selenium python script

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing the issue that when I am logging in to codeforces.com through my python selenium script, my login details are not getting saved in cookies, which I have enabled in my code, so each time I run the script I have to log in again.

When I manually log in to codeforces.com, and after closing the tab I open the site again, I am still logged in. I want to achieve this with my python code.

```
# this is the code to go to codeforces.com page in which I have enabled cookies
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/kanish/.config/google-chrome/Default")
w = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
w.get('https://codeforces.com/')
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641449/8125224

Comment: can you tell me what is use of line  w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)  in the code there

Comment: means what is this given path for

Comment: @KanishAnand executable_path means the path where you have chromedriver.exe on your machine.

Comment: You have to either get the cookie that contains the log in info and load it or save a browser profile where your credentials are saved.

Comment: okay . thanks @JeffC , but can you tell how to save a browser profile because first option of saving cookies I have done in above code ( if it is correct) ?

Comment: You don't have an code related to cookies in your currently posted code. If you want examples of loading profiles, etc. if you google, you will find a bunch.