# How to not get the "Chrome is being controlled by automated software" on Firefox when using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automation, geckodriver

So I was messing around with Selenium with Python and I wanted to automate some stuff such as, if I write Netflix on the script Netflix opens, some power options change, etc...
The problem is, I'm using Firefox and, when I open it I just get the robot icon near the search bar and the search bar itself gets those bars on the foreground.
I've tried a lot of stuff, including the good ol' "snatch and grab code from a stranger and put it there even if you don't know what it does or if it works" and... It did not.
The problem is that getting recognized as a bot doesn't save passwords and accounts, and after opening Firefox on Netflix for example I always end up opening other tabs that won't have my password as well.
Anyone knows how to not get recognized as a bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove this label, but you can load profile as it was shown here e.g.

[How do you use credentials saved by the browser in auto login script in python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641019/how-do-you-use-credentials-saved-by-the-browser-in-auto-login-script-in-python-2)

In this topic, there are Chrome and Firefox examples

Comment: thanks but now there is another issue, when i put in my profile as a parameter it just doesn't launch.

Comment: No error, just doesn't open the browser sometimes or it takes like 5 minutes to open it

Comment: So I figured it out. loading the profile takes about 122489395% of my processing power and everything stops. Really fun stuff

Comment: Maybe make sense to try Chrome instead of Firefox