# Is there a way to stop selenium from being redirected to login? Scraping Instagram with no api

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I am trying to scrape Instagram posts using selenium without using an API. The problem I run into is that Instagram will automatically redirect me to

`https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/`

instead of grabbing the link of the post I want. Is there a way to stop Instagram from redirecting me on selenium?
here is an example of a json link I am trying to go to instead of the redirected account logins:

`https://www.instagram.com/kingjames/?__a=1`

I dont want to have to log into an Instagram account.

Comment: Have you tried like this - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641449/16452840)

Answer (score 0):

It probably does not work properly because Instagram does not like datacenter ip ranges and it throws 302 redirect to login in this case. Try residential proxies.