# How to open a already logged-in chrome browser in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open a browser that is logged in to my gmail account like my default browser in selenium.  Is there a way to do this?

edit:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

this method does not work for me.

Comment: I dont want to login with code, because it asks two factor authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use credentials saved by the browser in auto login script in python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641019/how-do-you-use-credentials-saved-by-the-browser-in-auto-login-script-in-python-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Chrome Options

Chrome options are very particular on how you call them. Syntax needs to be followed with perfection. **Correct your below syntax errors** by changing your old code:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path")
```

To the following code:

```
userdatadir = 'C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data'
chromeOptions.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={userdatadir}")
```

Comment: yes this was it, i should have not included /Default at the end of User Data.  when i deleted it, the code worked.

Comment: @user279163 glad this solved it for you. Could you accept this as the solution?

Comment: i dont know how, is upvoting work for you?

Comment: @user279163 There should also be a check mark by my answer. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your profile that you use to open browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx-release/') # this work for linux, if you use windows, you can find this file in local AppData
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver', firefox_profile =profile)
```

This will use your standard profile that you use with your standard browser, including logins, cookies etc.

*Edit:
I used firefox here, but the same principle works with chrome as well.*

Answer (score 0):

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={CHROME_USER_DIR}")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")
```

This will open the Default Profile in Chrome.

The `user-data-dir` looks something like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

To open a different profile, replace the `Default` with your profile directory